# Spring transaction management for read lock

Tags: java, database, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I am using Spring for my transaction management. I am using @Transactional to implement spring transaction in my application. One of my scenario is, two instances of my application reading all records of a particular table. After reading and processing records these records will get deleted. But my problem is that before one instance completes read, processing and deleting other instance read these records again. In order to tackle this, I am planning to use read lock in the transaction so that until first transaction completes all the records get locked. How can I implement this using Spring declarative annotations. Any help is appreciated. I am using DB2 as my DB.
Thanks.

Comment: A read lock isn't enough if you're going to delete the rows. What are you using to access the database? Repositories? JdbcTemplate?

Comment: I will delete the rows in a single transaction after reading and processing it. But the second instance is reading those records during that time , which I don't want. Is Serializable isolation help me?

Comment: Not really, you need to do `SELECT FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED DATA` to get good throughput and have both do some actual work.

Comment: DEFAULT (spring-tx-isolation) defaults to the isolation "of the underlying datasource", configure this or try (at least) `READ_COMMITTED` ...before you go for `SERIALIZABLE`...

Comment: Don't go for serializable, it won't do you any good. The transactions will be rolling back constantly, and you'll be wasting time redoing them instead of processing rows.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to lock the rows you read for update, and skip locked rows at select. In raw SQL this would be

```
SELECT * FROM FOO FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED DATA FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY;
```

this way you won't mess with the rows in use by the other transaction, and both can happily process 100 rows at a time. The isolation level should be `READ COMMITTED` (presumably the default you're using).

Comment: Hi Kayaman,Thanks for giving me a straight answer. But unfortunately I am not in a position to update SQL statement which require a lot of approvals. Is there anyway I can do it without changing SQL statements.

Comment: If you're not in a position to do your job, then quit and find one where you are. You're allowed to change transaction attributes, but you can't touch the SQL? What is the sense in that?

Comment: You might as well just use a **single** instance of the application instead of doing the job poorly. I can't believe they allow you to change the transaction attributes, if you're not allowed to touch the SQL.

Comment: I just tried with "FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED DATA FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY" with my select query and it seems that both application is able to read the same rows. This select query is not locking selected rows from reading by other instance.

Comment: Then there's something wrong. `SELECT...FOR UPDATE` locks the rows pessimistically for the duration of the transaction (or throws an exception if no transaction exists). You can test it yourself if you have access to a DB2 instance where you can run queries. What's your isolation level? Are you sure you're running the right queries? Is your database server possessed by demons?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some distribution mechanism by which each instance reads/processes only specific records which is is different from the other instance. 
For example, 
1. Apply mod %2 function on the key column 
After reading a set of records from database:
Instance-1 should process records which have key%2=0 and discard/not process other records
Instance-2 should process records which have key%2=1 and discard/not process other records 
In this way even though same records could be read by both instances, we are sure they will be processed by only one node.

Comment: Why would they even read the other records? The database is perfectly capable of selecting only rows that have an id MOD 2 of 0 or 1.

Comment: I suggested so because the Jewel mentioned that he/she cannot change the SQL and needs something to be done only via code. Otherwise yes, we can definitely update SQL for this.

Comment: Hi, This looks a good idea but will work for two instances. If more than two instances trying to read, I think this approach wont work.